# PyAudio and Matplotlib crash when used together

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pyaudio

Running the following code:

```
import threading
import pyaudio
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def output():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream_ = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                    channels=1,
                    rate=8000,
                    output=True)

    stream_.stop_stream()
    stream_.close()
    p.terminate()


output_thread = threading.Thread(target=output, args=())
output_thread.start()
output_thread.join()

fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax0.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

causes Python to crash with the error below. How might I solve this? I am running Python 3.8, PyAudio 0.2.11 and Matplotlib 3.3.1 and Mac Os version 10.15.5.

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [4840]

Application Specific Information:
The current event queue and the main event queue are not the same. This is probably because _TSGetMainThread was called for the first time off the main thread. _TSGetMainThread was called for the first time here: 
0   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff36993345 _TSGetMainThread + 138
1   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff3699324a GetThreadGlobals + 26
2   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff3699d5e4 NewPtrClear + 14
3   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff369b4aba AVLInit + 62
4   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff369b49f1 __INIT_Folders_block_invoke + 9
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f603658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f6047de _dispatch_once_callout + 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok if I run:

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

before I create the thread I can avoid this crash. I'm guessing this allows me to call _TSGetMainThread on the main thread for the first time.